# Open image in modal (link in one div img in another)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a dot-front that when hovered over it flips and shows a dot-back with a link. If I click the link it should open a modal with a preview image.
I think that the problem is in the jquery where I wrote closest and find, but I don't know how to fix it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pop').on('click', function() {
    console.log("pop");
    $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('#modal-icon01').closest(".div-img").find('.front img').attr('src'));
    $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.div-img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div-img img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.div-img span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 200px;
}

.div-img > .front {
  position: absolute;
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  background: #0f1013;
  border: solid 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 150px;
}

.div-img > .back {
  position: absolute;
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  background: #0f1013;
  border: solid 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 150px;
}

.div-img:hover > .front {
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.div-img:hover > .back {
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="div-img">
  <div class="back">
    <center><span><a class="pop" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Pizza Hut Delivery<br>(De ce Pizza Hut)</a></span></center>
  </div>
  <div class="front">
    <center><img src="http://patyshibuya.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/04.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;"></center>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add jquery.min.js before script or in just above closing body tag

Comment: My eyes! Why you use `<center>` tag? It is deprecated and should not be used. It's harmful for SEO

Answer (score 0):

I Dont see the id called `modal-icon01` but base on your html file you can access the img through this:

```
$('.pop').on('click', function() {
        console.log("pop");
        var image = $(".div-img").find('.front').find('img').attr('src');
        $('#imagepreview').attr('src', image);
        $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
    });
```

Then dont forget to check if your jquery.js is attact before your script.

Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks, a few minutes after you've posted I've noticed that there was no id modal_icon01 (it was an old idea that i threw away and forgot to change the code). I changed that id with $(this) and now it works. Basically now it does what it should. Th edot flips, then when you click the link the modal opens with it's big sized image. Now i"m figuring out how to add links. wish me luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to add `Jquery` library then you have to declare what does `.modal` means ?
you can take the shortcut and just add bootstrap library with jquery and it will work fine, check this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4fxosm4/1/)

**Updated with image attached**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. Bootstrap includes were missing. And secondly, seems some of the HTML is missing in your question as I can't find this ID `modal-icon01`.

Try the below code and let me know:

```js
$('.pop').on('click', function() {
  console.log("pop");
  $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
});
```

```css
.div-img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div-img img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.div-img span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 200px;
}

.div-img>.front {
  position: absolute;
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  background: #0f1013;
  border: solid 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 150px;
}

.div-img>.back {
  position: absolute;
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  background: #0f1013;
  border: solid 1px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 150px;
}

.div-img:hover>.front {
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.div-img:hover>.back {
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="div-img">
  <div class="back">
    <center><span><a class="pop" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Pizza Hut Delivery<br>(De ce Pizza Hut)</a></span></center>
  </div>
  <div class="front">
    <center><img src="http://patyshibuya.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/04.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;"></center>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed  JavaScript Library File reference which is most required to perform click operation or any and to enable bootstrap model need bootstrap js. And also you are trying to find **modal-icon01** in `$('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('#modal-icon01').closest(".div-img").find('.front img').attr('src'));` which is not found, try to replace with this jquery 
`var imageSrc = $(".div-img").find('.front').find('img').attr('src');`
here you storing image path by targating to its src by finding it parent class and its tag. check this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2L2Lred2/)